# Graph vertex and degrees

Tags: graph-theory

I need to prove that if a graph $G$ has minimum degree 1, maximum degree $k$ and order $n > 2k$, then $G $ has at least 3 vertices with the same degree.
I took the classic approach with the handshaking lemma but it didn't really get anywhere, i also tried to prove that such a graph with $n=2k$ is possible but adding a node will mess everything up but couldn't prove building such a graph is possible.

Comment: @PaulHudford can I? I'm trying to prove that's true for n

Comment: @bof why 2k+1 vertices? if that's true then it's obvious!

Comment: @bof I had a lapsus brutus, sorry, what I meant is how do I prove such a graph with groups of 2 with k different degrees is not impossible to build?

Comment: The converse seems perfect to me. I pretty much doubted if the graph $G$ would have degrees 1,2,3,4,...,k but then I realized that if there aren't nodes with every degree (i.e no nodes with degree 2), there wouldbe just more nodes with higher degrees, due to the fact that every node has a degree of at least 1, anyway I found another way by induction of proving this while building such graph, so thank you you've been very helpful I'll be closing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the question answered I remark that since there are $k$-possible degrees for vertices of $G$ and $G$ has at least $2k+1$ vertices, by pigeonhole principle there is a degree common for three vertices of $G$.

Comment: Indeed. I actually replied by proving u can recursively build a graph with $n=2k$ and WLOG you can see why adding an extra node is impossible